# cross-compile for ARM64, understanding make TARGET=aarch64

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, arm64

I'm trying to cross-compile a library for ARM64, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 host system for a build
and the way I'm doing the cross-compile as

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install crossbuild-essential-arm64
```

and do the make

```
make -j 4 TARGET=aarch64
```

wonder what a compiler is invoked? Is it possible to set the latest `gcc` from ARM?

FYI. I'm trying to follow [TensorFlow cross-compile for ARM64](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_arm64#cross-compile_for_arm64) and set the latest [GNU Toolchain for ARM64](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads).

Comment: `TARGET=aarch64` just sets an environment variable. What happens with that depends entirely on the Makefile.

Comment: OK. Thank you. What/how is compiler set for this cross-compilation since I want to use latest version which I installed, can I override the default/actual setting for the arm64 compiler?

Comment: Only the Makefile can tell you that.

Comment: How do I check for TARGET, TARGET_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX, CXX, CC, ... other variables?